# Can gdb/gdbserver stream core dumps off-target?

Tags: gdbserver

I'm facing an embedded target that doesn't have any local storage in which to save a dump file.

Comment: but you sure have root file system with /tmp/ writable folder, right? Can you make folder in it and map/mount it to network share?

Comment: unfortunately filesystem mount is not an option. I was hoping to use ssh to stream off box but unfortunately gcore and friends tend to seek around the output file which sort of precludes this. i was thinking i’d need to write my own version of gcore that instead of seeking in the file would emit a block header (offset,size) that i could use to reassemble the stream off target.